# Name for multi-element data-structures in Functional Programming?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Multi-element data-structures, like `Streams` and `Lists`, seem to have some distinct properties. For example,

- They are `Monoids`
- They are mergeable (You can have a default `Semigroup` implementation that merges the elements, without knowing about the element type)

Single-element data-structures are also `Monoids`, but cannot have a semi-group implementation without knowing about the `type` they contain (e.g. `Option`, `Future`, etc.) They also do not guarantee that the element still "exists" after it has been added/combined.

Is there a name for this type of data-structure that contains all elements that have been added (combined)? My aim is to create a distinct type-class for these types of data-structures to distinguish them from other Monoids/Semigroups.

Comment: Semigroup combines values. I distinguish three notions of combining: Accumulating (e.g. `List` monoid), aggregating (e.g. `Sum`) and picking (e.g. `First`). This is only my personal terminology though. Accumulating doesn't lose information whereas aggregation does.

Comment: With accumulating you can postpone the decision how to further combine the element values (provided they are also monoids). This distinguishes such monoids from other ones but I don't think it is enough to justify a distinct type class.

Comment: You can call them [FreeMonoid](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/10/strings-lists-and-sequences-as-a-monoid/)

Comment: If you want to have some "collection" of A and the monoid is about collection, and not about A, then the type class is called [`MonoidK`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoidk.html) in Cats. Free Monoid, is basically a `List` in disguise, so it would also be handled by this type class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what you ask is sill a monoid. If you want to be able to combine `A` and `A` into another `A`, there is some idea of empty `A` that doesn't change the result, and the operations is associative - then this is monoid no matter if:

- `A` is some plain type that you combine as numbers
- `A` is some `F[B]` where monoidal properties belong to `F` and would be true for all possible `B`

For practical reasons there are 2 type classes in Cats:

- [`Monoid[A]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html) which gives you `combine(a1: A, a2: A): A`, `empty: A` and everything you can achieve with these two
- [`MonoidK[F[_]]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoidk.html), which is basically a factory: `[A] => Monoid[F[A]]`, but with utilities that allow you to defer the application of `A` e.g. `combineK[A](fa1: F[A], fa2: F[A]): F[A]`, `emptyK[A]: F[A]`

Same is true for semigroup, where you have `Semigroup`, `SemigroupK` and also `Semigrupal`, which is a semigroup on types (addition of `A` and `B`, means creation of a tuple `(A, B)`, and `(A + B) + C` = `A + (B + C)` if we assume equality up to isomorphism). This shows that we don't need to invent new algebras, old one works just fine, though sometimes different use cases might require a slightly different implementations.